# Reading values in a csv file while deleting unwanted ones

Tags: python, csv

I want to read a csv file that contains floats and arrays. I only want to collect float values and get rid of array ones.

I have tried the following code :

```
with open('resultsMC_100_var.csv', "r") as input:
with open('new.csv', "w") as output :
    for line in input :
        if not line.count(('[') or (']')) :
           output.write(line)
```

But the problem is that array values are written on several lines so the code does not work as intended...

I show you the first line of my csv file so you can have an idea of how it is built :

```
51.3402815384;28.1789716134;76.7144759149;28.5590830355;50.719035557;4.83225361254;[  23.35145494   23.6919634    21.1406396    77.35953884  121.68508966   23.02126533   24.64623985   22.30757623   59.53286234   86.01880338   22.34363071   29.75759786   30.94420056   27.24198645   21.62989704
   22.57036406   23.09155954   26.32781992   22.82521813   99.12230864
   22.04329951   22.50081984  104.84634521   59.48921929   34.47985424
```

What I would like to do is a code that reads all the values, then stops if it meets the symbol `[` and then reads again as soon as it meets `]`. I do not know how to do it properly and I have not found a similar topic on this website so I will be thankful to anyone who can helps me.

Comment: Use the `{}` button in your editor to markup the data. Also, please post the line with the closing bracket included.

Comment: Hi ! 
Concerning the line that you are mentioning, here it is :  22.72918644  121.53180393   21.37333868   42.80311541   22.09749408];
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can the `[` and `]` be on different lines?  Also, how big are the CSV files?  Could you update your question to show what your expected output CSV file should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your statement is that `line.count(('[') or (']'))` is the same as writing  `line.count('[')`, since a non-empty string is evaluated to True...

A simple solution here would be to use a regex:

```
import re

with open('test.txt', "r") as f:
    content = f.read()

    with open('new.txt', "w") as output :
        new_line = re.sub(r"\[[^\[\]]*\]", "", content, flags=re.MULTILINE)
        output.write(new_line)
```

Comment: Hi @olinox14!
What your code does is collecting all the lines that do not include "[" or "]" but it is not what I want to do.
I want to collect all the values until I meet "[" and then collect again when I meet "]".
If I apply your code, I will collect all the values between "[" and "]" and I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not understand that. But no: with the current code, you'll copy each line wich does not contain any [ or ]. I'll update my answer in a minute

Answer (score 0):

You could try using regex. Here's what I think will work.

```
import re

inp = open("results.csv", "r")
inp_data = inp.read()

out_data = re.sub(r"\[[^\[\]]*\]", "", inp_data)
out = open("xyz.csv", "w")

out.write(out_data)
```

This first reads your input data into a string.
It then replaces all arrays with "". You can then write this updated string to a new file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Though, this regex won't work if an array covers multiple lines... Also, you should prefer using the [with statement](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) for opening files

Comment: Ah, I find that you're right. I'll edit my regex. Thanks for the with statement tip!